# CrossRider: What library method scope can be used in a popup?

Tags: crossrider

I have saved data in the `appAPI.db.async` database. And now I want to display it in the popup page.
Here's what I have in the popup page:

```
function crossriderMain($) {
    var db_keys = appAPI.db.async.getKeys();
    db_keys.forEach(
        function(key)
        {
            $("ul#id").append("<li>" + appAPI.db.async.get(key).url + "</li>");
        });
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul id="history">History</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

which doesn't give the intended result.
What I want to know is what's available for me when inside a popup page?.

Also, as an aside question: how do I open a browser tab from an HTML page in my resources directory, instead of a popup that won't take the whole screen space, in the `browserAction.onClick` handler?

Something like that in `background.js`:

```
appAPI.browserAction.onClick(
        function()
        {
            appAPI.tabs.create("/Resources/templates/history.html");
        }
    );
```

Thanks (:->)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to question 1**

[appAPI.db.async](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db.async) is asynchronous by design and hence you must use a callback to receive and use the values from the database. Additionally, it is not necessary to get the keys first and then their associated data; you can simply achieve your goal in one step using [appAPI.db.async.getList](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db.async-method-getList).

Hence, using your example the code should be:

```
function crossriderMain($) {
  appAPI.db.async.getList(function(arrayOfItems) {
    for (var i=0; i<arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
      $("ul#id").append("<li>" + arrayOfItems[i].value + "</li>");
    }
  });
}
```

**Answer to question 2**

To create a new tab that opens a resource page, use the [appAPI.openURL](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-openURL) method.

Hence, using your example the code should be:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  // When using a button, first set the icon!
  appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('images/icon.png');
  appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {
    appAPI.openURL({
      resourcePath: "templates/history.html",
      where: "tab",
    });
  });
});
```

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But you didn't tell me which scopes are available in the popup.

Comment: The popup scope is a scope of it's own and does not directly relate to the other scopes. I think you may be asking what APIs are available in the popup scope and you can see this info in our docs ([appAPI.browserAction.setPopup](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setPopup)).